# Call a Rest API from .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have been doing some API building in .Net Core and learning what is new.

I can not work out how to call the following

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetBooks")] 
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<BookDisplay>>> Get([FromQuery]  BookSearch bookSearch)
    {

        var books = await _bookManager.Search(bookSearch);

        var paginationMetadata = new
        {
            totalCount = books.TotalCount,
            pageSize = books.PageSize,
            currentPage = books.CurrentPage,
            totalPages = books.TotalPages
        };
        Response.Headers.Add("X-Pagination", JsonSerializer.Serialize(paginationMetadata));
        var links = CreateGetLinks(bookSearch, books.HasNext, books.HasPrevious);
        var booksToReturn = new  
        {
            Value = books,
            links
        };

        return Ok(booksToReturn);             
    }
```

I can call this okay through swagger and get the follow

**Request URL**

https://localhost:5001/api/Books?Author=IanFleming&Style=Spy

**Server response**

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "Author": "Ian Fleming",
      "Stye": "Spy",
      "Title": "Dr No"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "Author": "Ian Fleming",
      "Stye": "Spy",
      "Title": "Casino Royale"
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://localhost:5001/api/Books/Author=Ian%20Fleming&Style=Spy&PageNumber=1&PageSize=10",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    }
  ]
}



    Response headers
     content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
     date: Tue, 26 May 2020 12:18:04 GMT 
     server: Kestrel 
     x-pagination: {"totalCount":2,"pageSize":10,"currentPage":1,"totalPages":1}
```

This all works fine, when testing and calling with swagger.
But I have been building a .Net Core application that call it with the following code,

```
   public async Task<IEnumerable<BookDisplay>> BookSearch(BookSearch search)
    {
        try
        {
            var searchJson =
            new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(search), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


            return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<BookDisplay>>
                        (await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync($"/api/Books?Author=IanFleming&Style=Spy"), new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I get the following error
*The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DTO.BookDisplay]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.*

I know I have skipped corners by hard coding the in the parameters, but I couldn't get that part to work.

I also want to get the header data and the links object so I can use that to discover more parts of the API and put in paging on the UI.

I need the search to be passed in as a parameter object, because when building the API I will not know what fields the consumer of the API will want to search on so can not have it as part of the URL.

Comment: Without seeing all your code, the likely reason is that the response isn't an array, it's an object with a property `value` that is an array. The code posted tries to deserialize the response to an `IEnumerable`, which is an invalid mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is deserialization issue. Json data does not match type you are deserializing.

Here are working dto classes based on your json data:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Value[] value { get; set; }
    public Link[] links { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Stye { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string rel { get; set; }
    public string method { get; set; }
}
```

So deserialization can be done with this:

```
return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Rootobject>
                        (await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync($"/api/Books?Author=IanFleming&Style=Spy"), new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
```

Visual Studio has good way to [paste json as classes](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-paste-json-as-classes-or-xml-as-classes-in-visual-stu/).

Comment: Cheers, I had completely forgotten about the json paste tool in Visual Studio.  This solved my return problem.

Answer (score -1):

Without spending a lot of time on this, my suggestion would be to deserialise the object to a concrete type such as a `List`, rather than an `IEnumerable` (which is not a concrete type).

```
        return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<BookDisplay>>
                    (await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync($"/api/Books?Author=IanFleming&Style=Spy"), new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
```

Comment: json data in question does not seem to be collection at all